# Overriding `query()` in ContentProvider prevents Recent Suggestions From Showing

Tags: android, search

I have an app that stores user search history.  I am now adding Custom Suggestions as well.  This required me to add one more method, `query()` and override it in my `MyCustomSuggestionProvider` class.

However, doing this prevents Recent Suggestions from showing.  They are still being stored in the suggestions.db.  The moment I delete the `query()` method to test, recent suggestions come back.

Does anyone know how to make these two things work together?

Comment: Well, first you have to decide what you actually want to happen. It sounds like you want both recent suggestions and your custom suggestions, but in what mix? Do you want the recent suggestions shown first? Or do you want the custom suggestions shown first? Do you want to show all of them, or only half of the custom and half of the recent? After you decide that, try calling `super.query()` from your overriding implementation of `query` and then merging your results as appropriate.

Comment: @kabuko  Well, I figured out my question but that isn't what was going on.  I need to find out how to merge them, but the columns need to match I beleive and I am having a hard time figuring that one out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not overiding query(), it was how I was handling it.  Here is my solution:

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    Cursor recentCursor = super.query(uri, projection, selection,
            selectionArgs, sortOrder);

    query = selectionArgs[0];
    if (query == null || query.length() < 3) {

        return recentCursor;

    } else {

        query = selectionArgs[0];

        MatrixCursor customCursor = new MatrixCursor(COLUMN_NAMES);

        SearchSuggestionObject[] suggestions = getSuggestionsFromWebFeed(query);

        for (SearchSuggestionObject suggestion : suggestions) {

            customCursor.addRow(new Object[] { suggestion.getId(),
                    suggestion.getItem(), suggestion.getCat(),
                    suggestion.getItem(), suggestion.getItem(),
                    suggestion.getCat(), "android.intent.action.SEARCH" });
        }

        return customCursor;
    }
}
```